# vb.net method constraints

Tags: vb.net, generics, constraints

I have a class which I have marked as MustInherit (called BasePage), with a generic method that is marked as MustOverride:

```
Protected MustOverride Function SaveData(Of T As {BaseClass})(ByVal item As T) As T
```

What I want to do is force the users of this method to only supply a type of BaseClass, or anything derived from it.  Also, when a class derives from BasePage, it should work on only one derived class from BaseClass:

```
Protected Overrides Function SaveData(Of T As BaseClass)(ByVal item As T) As T
  Dim grad As DerivedClass = CType(item, DerivedClass)

  Return grad
End Function
```

However, when I try to do the cast, it flags up the following error:

```
Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to 'DerivedClass'.
```

All the documentation I have read suggests that this should work.  However, it's not a big problem if it doesn't work, as I can work around by making a non-generic method that only accepts BaseClass.

Any ideas?

Comment: What documentation suggests that this will work? You're trying to cast `BaseClass` to `DerivedClass`. How does the compiler know that your `BaseClass` object is a `DerivedClass` object?

Comment: Does the constraint `(Of T As {BaseClass}) ` not mean that the class supplied should either be of type `BaseClass` or something derived from it?

Comment: Yes, it does. The problem is, not *all* `BaseClass` objects are *also* `DerivedClass` objects. So you can't **necessarily** downcast from a `BaseClass` object to a `DerivedClass` object. The compiler won't let you do this because it can't verify that it's valid.

Comment: Eric Lippert recently blogged on this subject (his examples are C#, but the points he makes remain valid): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the documentation I have read suggests that this should work.

On the contrary: it *can’t* work. The type `T` derives from  `BaseClass` – but nothing in your code tells the compiler that it is convertible to `DerivedClass`. For example, it could be of type `IndependentlyDerivedClass` which is a *sibling* of `DerivedClass`.

However, the following cast works:

```
Dim grad As DerivedClass = DirectCast(DirectCast(item, BaseClass), DerivedClass))
```

Notice that I’m using `DirectCast` in place of `CType`. This is a best-practice when casting in class hierarchies since `DirectCast` *only* allows such casts (these, and boxing/unboxing conversions) so you minimize the risk of accidentally calling a conversion operator (which can happen when you’re using `CType` on non-related types).

Comment: Will change the method so that it doesn't use generics.  Seems like the sensible thing to do.

Comment: @ScottD In this particular case: yes.

Comment: To avoid runtime error, this should be `TryCast(..., DerivedClass))`. Followed by test that the result is not `Nothing`. Then, if a `BaseClass` item is *not* a `DerivedClass`, the code will not attempt to use it as a `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You typically do something like this

```
Public MustInherit Class BasePage(Of T As BaseClass)
    Public MustOverride Function Savedata(ByVal Item As T) As T
End Class

Public Class derivedPage
    Inherits BasePage(Of DerivedClass)

    Public Overrides Function Savedata(ByVal Item As DerivedClass) As DerivedClass
        Dim grad As DerivedClass = Item
        Return grad
    End Function

End Class

Public MustInherit Class BaseClass

End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

End Class
```